# Selenium webdriver for Django/React for Github Actions

Tags: reactjs, django, selenium-webdriver, github-actions

So, to use webdriver for a django react project, I start the backend and frontend and then I use the url with webdriver, and it works fine locally.
But I can't do that with Github Actions as `python manage.py runserver` and `npm start` get into infinite loops...

How to get around this to make selenium work on Github Actions?